# Exchange - send notification to other email when a new message comes

Tags: exchange, smtp, exchange-2016, microsoft

I have Microsoft Exchange 2016 and I would like to create notifications for users, when they get new message on account user1@example.com, they will automatically receive notification (NOT FORWARDED MESSAGE!) on the mailbox user1@yyy.com

yyy.com is completly diffrent mailbox and mail server.

I tried to do it through mailflow on exchange administration center:
[TUTORIAL](http://www.expta.com/2015/07/how-to-notify-users-when-email-is.html)
but in new rule I can only send notification to user, whose account is on example.com exchange server.

Comment: Yes, incident report only works for internal Exchange objects, and cannot send this report to an external contact.
Therefore, I suppose that your requirement cannot be achieved if not forwarding message to this person.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,incident report only works for internal users, as a workaround, you can create a mail contact and set the email address to "User1@yyy.com", then use transport rule to send an incident to this contact.